# Probability in a given time period

Tags: statistics

If a meteor on average is seen at a rate of 0.75 per minute, what is the probability that more than one meteor will be seen in a minute?

Comment: Use the Poisson Distribution

Answer (score 1):

As David stated, poisson distribution. Poisson distribution is great for finding probabilities of something occurring over a course of time.

$$P(x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^x}{x!}$$

You want
$$P (x>1)$$
$$1-P (x\leq 1)$$
$$1\text{}-\text{}P(x=0,x=1)$$

Thus,

$$1-[{e^{-0.75}}*(1+\frac{0.75}{1!})]$$
= $$.1733$$

using "PoissonCDF" in the graphing calculator yields $.8267$, thus $1$ - $.8267$ = $.1733$ as desired.

using "ppois" in R

```
 1-ppois(1,.75)
 =.1733
```

So there is about a $17.33$% chance that more than one meteor will be seen in a minute